# Any alternative main stream programming methodologies to OOP using C#?

Tags: c#, paradigms

As far as programming languages go, I love C#, and for that matter all the good that comes from the .net framework (LINQ, etc).

My main concern is I seem to be churning out too much code, and using OOP, I have a concern my code isn't always that easy to manage.

I want to continue using C# and .Net, but are there any other approaches to applying the language to get overall less code, and easier to manage compared to text book OOP?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes - I've found the same problem.  OOP isn't the best way to solve all problems.  However, C# supports the functional paradigm quite well and I've used it successfully on a few projects now.

There is an interesting talk here with respect to simplification which should give you some food for thought at least: http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/design-architecture/simple-is-better

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to experiment try AOP / C# like [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120330152158/http://www.dotnetdevnet.com/Downloads/Meetings/2009/October/AOP.pdf) and [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20151029121853/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saveenr/archive/2008/11/20/c-aop-elegant-tracing-with-postsharp-and-aspect-oriented-programming.aspx). the PDF has a fine sheet on pros and cons.

Answer (score 1):

Aspect Oriented Programming may allow you to gain some efficiency by handling your "crosscutting concerns" in a uniform way.  There are other possible benefits, but in my opinion it would be useful to you!

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming
http://www.sharpcrafters.com/aop.net

Answer (score 0):

Before straying too far into differing methodologies, make sure to take advantage of [refactoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) to simplify and consolidate your code.  Here is Fowler's catalog, the "[alpha List of refactorings](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/index.html)," each of which can help you improve and manage your C# code.

By learning to effectively design for reuse and by optimizing your application of interfaces, abstract classes, class hierarchies, dependency injection, and similar tools that exist within the standard object-orientated methodology, you may find yourself well on your way to achieving your desired results.

Beyond that, @Chris Smith has already pointed you to the fact that newer versions of C# (3.5 and 4.0) have added  several functional programming capabilities that may help you make your code rock!

If you find you like functional programming, give Microsoft's new [F# language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/fsharp/cc742182) a try!  It's actually more like "object-functional," a mixture of the two methodologies.  You may also want to know that you can [mix F# and C# in the same .NET Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817248/patterns-to-mix-f-and-c-in-the-same-solution).

I also concur with the other commentators that AOP certainly has its uses!

Answer (score 0):

OOPS may have caused more code but If your application is large, the reduced complexity OOPS brings in would have resulted in maintainable,manageable code and clarity. If this is not the case and you feel it as a burden I am sure you might have used improperly. check if your classes are representing the domain objects properly and the communication among them is close to how it happens in the real world system that you try to simulate in program.

In C#, too much code is not a realistic reason to move away from OOPS IMHO. A paradigm shift should have a much more valid reason, in reality.

one can do 'structured programming' in C#..but I guess it will be a waste of time and effort.And most of the mainstream alternatives make use of OOPS too.

Answer (score 0):

I recently realized that the new features of C#, especially version 9, allow new non-OOP ways of organizing code. As a result I produced the F package at https://github.com/kofifus/F which is still a work in progress but has been successfully used in medium sized projects.

The general idea is to decouple the OOP concept of 'class' into separate State, Data and Logic and the package provides code to greatly facilitate that. Perhaps you can find the ideas there useful.